# Why does the 'Home' key, to scroll to the top, only work on meta.stackoverflow?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, internet-explorer-7

When I am on Meta, I can push the HOME button on my keyboard (like on other sites) to go to the top of the page.

However, when on any other site on Stack Exchange, this is not possible unless you click in the margin, which is not always visible/available when you resize the window.

Why is there this difference? Is there a workaround?

OS: Windows Vista

Browser: Internet Explorer 7 (limited to this browser by company policy)

Comment: It works for me on all pages on all sites (Windows XP + Chrome). What OS & browser are you running?

Comment: Edited the question with this info.

Comment: use spacebar (down) and shift+spacebar (up) to scroll. I try to avoid use of mouse as much as possible and usually spacebar scrolling works on every site (not only stackexchange)

Comment: Check to see if the sites that don't scroll have IE in compat view (perhaps because you commented, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114602/pressing-the-enter-key-to-complete-a-comment-switches-internet-explorer-8-to-com ) and if so, put it back to normal. One of the things compat mode does to me is mess up keyboard scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems solved now. I have no idea what made this problem occur in the first place. Also the workaround presented in comments by bestsss is usefull.