# New beta theme styling messes up sporadically

Tags: bug, design

Ever since the new beta theme was released I've been having a problem with it sporadically messing up. I reported the bug over a month ago [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme/127773#127773), as requested, but that thread seems to have been abandoned. And as a moderator it is a huge inconvenience for me, because I am unable to see if there are any flags I need to address.

The issue is that the links in the header disappear, as seen here:

[image]

I've also noticed that when this happens a horizontal scroll bar appears, even though it is not needed, and the social buttons disappear from the right sidebar:

[image]

Additionally, within each thread the community ads also mess up:

[image]

The new thing now, is that the community bulletin also gets messed up:

[image]

It all seems to be related to one underlying problem, as they all happen at the same time. However, the issue I'm most concerned about is the links disappearing in the header, as it impedes me from properly attending to the community.

I have only seen this issue in IE8. I've never seen it in FF, and I have not tested it in Chrome. It happens sporadically, but I've noticed that it tends to crop up a lot after I post a comment or answer and I get a message from the browser about the compatibility mode.

Comment: Have you tried turning on/off compatibility mode?  As well this is potentially the same bug or related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114602/154510

Comment: Interesting. I had not seen that other bug report. It seems related, but I think my issue may be slightly different. Sometimes my issue is triggered without submiting a comment. Or maybe the problem is getting progressively worse. I'll test with the compatibility mode to see what happens.