# Community bulletin text flows out of box

Tags: support, internet-explorer, community-bulletin

A minor formatting bug, I think:

The box displaying the Community Bulletin appears to be a little broken. The bottom edge of the box currently runs through the text of the Arqade blog post announcement - see the screen grab below.

I'm using IE 8.0.7601.17504.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off **Compatibility View** (broken window icon next to address bar) and it will look as intended.

Comment: You're right - that's interesting, I didn't realise it was on. Wonder how that happened...

Comment: Hmmmm. Bizarrely, posting that comment triggered compatibility view again. Bloody IE, wish I could use Chrome from the office...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114602/commenting-switches-internet-explorer-8-to-compatibility-mode