# A certain meta page does not open right in IE

Tags: bug, status-norepro, internet-explorer

Try to open this page in IE (8 and 9 have been tested) [works fine in compat mode]

[Null bytes accepted as part of text (not really)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145534/potential-security-risk-null-bytes-accepted-as-part-of-text)

Only the title seems to load.

Is it because of my RTL characters? or is it something else?

---

Just for reference (this is where the issue was brought up): [Chat transcript [beware of erroneous nose]](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/ie-rtl-error)

Comment: It's because you're a communist!

Comment: @mccarthynator at least I am not from Canada.

Comment: That's what you keep trying to convince me. . . eh?

Comment: Thanks, I can now check *downvoting a question with a link to a chat transcript where there's a picture of a nose* off my bucket list.

Comment: @YannisRizos you have a problem with noses eh?

Comment: @YannisRizos I added a warning :-P

Comment: No. not really, my problem is more that I don't want to click a link to find out what you're talking about. Too bored to move whatever useful in the transcript here? Well I'm too bored to follow the link and try to find out what's going on, while having someone's nose staring at me.

Comment: @YannisRizos what is useful is aready in the question. The transcript is just for reference. The OP here has **all relevant information**

Comment: That nose looks exploitable.

Comment: Ok next question: Why the hell are you posting pictures of noses in chat anyway?

Comment: @YannisRizos that picture is out of context. if you look at the context you will know the reason why.

Comment: Yeah, I should have known it was rchern's fault... That said, sharing the transcript is utterly pointless, the only relevant info in there is "Anyone else having problems opening this question?" & "I just get a blank page". How is that _useful information_?

Comment: @YannisRizos never said it was. The meat of my question is all here.

Comment: Ok next question: Why the hell are you using IE?

Comment: @YannisRizos haha **I** am not. The user in chat was. I am a Chrome guy all the way.

Comment: Ok next question: If this isn't your problem, why did you post this? (man, I can do this for hours ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos well I cannot. **Shabbat Shalom!**

Comment: Ok next question: What does Shabbat Shalom mean?

Comment: **Please avoid extended discussion in the comments. Do you want to automatically move this to a chat room very far away?**

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi [that brings me here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98926/155556)

Comment: @YannisRizos **google is your friend...** have a great weekend.

Comment: Oh come on, don't go, it's Friday, who am I going to troll if you go? ;p

Comment: @YannisRizos try the Workplace chat, it's THE place to be these days

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA That was a very good feature request, too bad it was declined... Not one of Jeff's finest moments.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this in IE10, or IE10 in IE9 emulation mode (press <kbd>f12</kbd> to get the developer tools to do so).

Comment: Happens to me on IE8. The browser goes to the IE7 compatibility mode automatically right away when I open it. Same as almost always [when I post a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114602/147640). If forced to IE8 mode with the F12 tools, indeed shows a blank page and a js error in wmd.js, line 22, symbol 147 (cannot set `text` property). If I then examine the page structure with F12, all (?) nodes are there, but all text nodes contain empty strings. I actually wanted to post a query myself, but then thought, oh well, it's IE8 and things happen.